# Connect a USB hub in Poky

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, yocto-project, lsusb

Running a Poky/Yocto distribution on a HW platform with a Renesas R-Car. I have a USB peripheral connected and when I `dmesg` I get this -

`[  121.481489] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd`

I just want to monitor traffic on it. When I connect it to ubuntu, I can use `screen ttyUSB0 4800` and can see the output from the peripheral which is sending data at 4800 baud. How do I do the same on this board? I dont see any `ttyUSB` show up under `/dev/` nor can I use `lsusb` in this distro.

Comment: What is the device? Presumably some sort of USB Serial adapter... do you have the `usb-serial` module available / built in?

Comment: You can always build `lsusb` for poky... it's in the `usbutils` package.